# How to prevent inputs with null values from querysring in MVC Form with GET method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with FormMethod.Get in a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Pages", new { filter = "Properties" }, FormMethod.Get))
```

This form when submitting sends all the inputs as querystring even if the inputs has  null values like:

```
http://localhost:1156/Pages/Search?q=anything&id=&t=
```

I want to prevent inputs with null values from being sent, so the url is like this:

```
http://localhost:1156/Pages/Search?q=anything
```

Comment: Are the empty values causing a problem of some kind?

Comment: I have a lot of inputs and I do not them to be shown if they are empty

Comment: Why are you not using POST method?

Comment: it is advanced search with paging and a lot of complicated things and that was the best way for me

Comment: I suppose you could intercept the form submit event with JavaScript, cancel the event, and build the URL manually to redirect the user.  Seems like a lot of work for what's essentially a non-issue in the first place though.

Comment: There is no difference when you use @Satpal method. The only difference is that you dont see e.g. `?id=`, what would be the problem?